# What is an intuitive explanation for a lay-person why controlling for a collider is bad practice while controlling for a confounder is good practice?

Tags: regression, causality, controlling-for-a-variable, causal-diagram

[Cinelli et al., 2022](https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r493.pdf) and [Wysnocki et al., 2022](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/25152459221095823#:%7E:text=Because%20the%20goal%20of%20statistical,as%20a%20mediator.%20Box%201) describe in technical terms how controlling for a collider can lead to biased estimates. If one needs to explain why one should not control for a collider to a non-technical audience of lay-people without a stats background, what would be an intuitive explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You could give examples

From what I've seen, most people introduce the ideas with the help of examples. Some fairly typical ones are:

**Collider:** player size $\to$ NBA $\leftarrow$ player skill

Among NBA players, smaller players may be more skilled than taller players. This is likely not because their size makes them skilled, but rather because both skill and size contribute to your chance of being drafted into the NBA, so people who are not exceptional at one, will have to be exceptional at the other. Controlling for whether or not a player made it to the NBA will give a relationship that's probably not true for players at large.

**Confounder:**
ice cream sales $\leftarrow$ sunshine $\to$ drowning incidents

There would seem to be a relationship between ice cream sales and drowning incidents because both are caused by a common factor. Controlling for the common factor removes the spurious correlation.